# Excel formula to return an adjacent value when two cells match between a range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how I am supposed to return a particular value, based upon a different value, within a specific range.

The data in question can have identical numbers because it's raw data that looks something like this.

[image]

The 2nd and 4th column is completely useless data, but it's not feasible to go into dozens and dozens of files to delete them before running the formula.

I initially tried index, such as `=INDEX(I2:I13,MATCH(O5,K2:K13,0))` to see if that gives me a possible solution.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTZTh.png]

However, because the column has a very high chance to have duplicates, it causes a problem because this function only returns the first value ever found (due to match function).

How can I find the **second** `620` which has the expected value of **`10.12724`** instead of the first instance that returns **`10.03533`** nor the 3rd instance that returns **`10.20601938`**?

The raw data itself has more than 5000 lines minimum and there is no guarantee on how many duplicate numbers there will be so it specifically needs to be `within a certain range`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, FILTER(I2:I18,K2:K18=O7), IFERROR(INDEX(x,2),INDEX(x,1)))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this wouldn't work if there are any more 620 values beneath 10.12724 could this be somehow done something like MAXIFS?

Comment: It's written in the first sentence. I'm trying to figure out how I am supposed to return a particular value,based upon a different value, within a specific range.

Your solution given solves the particular value upon a different value, but it doesn't give it within a specific range.

So something like; "Find the Angle value for a specific Intensity, between the ranges of 10.1141074 and 10.14036797.

Comment: It does, since what I am needing is the output being consistent be it wherever it is within the data. I specified `How can I find the second 620` because that was the second 620 within the entry. Therefore, it is neither to your question. If you use the reverse search function as you suggested, it will pickup the 3rd, 4th, or even the 70th 620 if it exists within the raw data. Which is not useful to me.

Comment: I used such a formula because that was what I tried so far. Stack Overflow had a `what did you try so far?` section in the question so I just wrote what I tried that gave me the closest result. But as I said, faulty solution as it only finds the first instance and my raw data has a large amount of same numbers.

Comment: @Curious_Canidae what should be the output if there is no second instance?

Comment: I edited the OP, I hope it is a little clearer. If there is no second instance, aka 620 NEVER reappears within the entire data. It would have the exact same result as `=INDEX(I2:I13,MATCH(O9,K2:K13,0))` which just goes from top to bottom. I tried out the MAXIFS suggestion... and it had the result of `10.206` (as I edited the OP). Which isn't it either... :(

Comment: Posted as per new update

Answer (score 0):

With this array formula:

`=INDEX(I1:K18,SMALL(IF(K1:K18=N1,ROW(1:18),ROWS(K1:K18)+1),P1),1)`

In cell N1:  The lookup_value

In cell P1:  The count of the instance

Replace in the formula the numbers `18` to the actual row-size of the table

[image]